# How to compare list of dicts in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have below list:

```
objList = [{
            'Name': 'keyboard',
            'objectId': [0, 1],
            'StartTime': '2022-01-10T13:18:17.098119',
            'IsCompleted': False,
            'MetaData': [{
                'Count': 2
            }]
}]


o = [{"keyboard": "Assembly"}, {"smallObjects": "Label"}]
```

I have to check if `objList` has all the dict with `Name` matching the key of dict in `o`. If not then print the `Name`. I have below working code:

```
if len(objList) != len(o):
    for i in o:
        for (k, v) in i.items():
            for obj in objList:
                if k == obj["Name"]:
                    print("Found {}".format(k))
                else:
                    print("Not found {}".format(k))
```

It seems to be working but not properly optimized as it has lot of `for` loop. Is there any other way we can optimize the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way to resolve your problem is to trap all `keys` and all values for key `Name` in 2 sets/lists, like this:

```
objList = [{
            'Name': 'keyboard',
            'objectId': [0, 1],
            'StartTime': '2022-01-10T13:18:17.098119',
            'IsCompleted': False,
            'MetaData': [{
                'Count': 2
            }]
}]
o = [{"keyboard": "Assembly"}, {"smallObjects": "Label"}]

all_keys = set().union(*(d.keys() for d in o))
names=[d['Name'] for d in objList]

for k in all_keys:
    if k in names:
        print("Found {}".format(k))
    else:
        print("Not found {}".format(k))
```